# maxima gradef differentiation

Tags: maxima, differentiation

I try to define the derivative of the standard normal pdf in terms of the function:

`φ(x) := exp (-x^2/2)/sqrt(2 * %pi);
gradef(φ(x),-x*φ(x));`

but if I type then:

```
diff(φ(x),x);
```

I get:

```
-(x*%e^(-x^2/2))/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(%pi))`
```

not as I want `-x*φ(x)`.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks do not

Karl

**EDiT**  :

*Unfortunately both suggestions do **not** work.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong; Maxima is just evaluating phi according to the definition you gave when you call `gradef`.

I can think of a couple of things to try. (1) Call `gradef` before defining phi. Then maybe you'll get phi in the output when you call `diff`. Not sure if that will work.

(2) Define the `gradef` using a noun expression, i.e., `gradef(φ(x),-x*'φ(x))`. Notice the single quote mark `'` before `φ(x)`; that makes a so-called noun expression in which the argument `x` may be evaluated but the function `φ` is not called. Later on in order to evaluate the function, when you want to, you can say `ev(someexpression, nouns)` to evaluate all noun expressions in `someexpression`.

EDIT: Here's another idea. This works for me. The previous ideas didn't work because φ gets evaluated too soon; this new idea goes to a greater length to prevent evaluation. Note that the gradef is defined for `'φ(x)`, so you have to write `diff('φ(x), x)` in order to apply the gradef.

```
(%i12) gradef('φ(x), -x*'φ(x));
(%o12)                        φ(x)
(%i13) diff('φ(x), x);
(%o13)                      - x φ(x)
```

The gradef produces a noun expression `-x*'φ(x)`, so to verbify it you can say:

```
(%i14) ev(%, nouns);
                                    2
                                   x
                                 - --
                                   2
                             x %e
(%o14)                 - -----------------
                         sqrt(2) sqrt(%pi)
```

Looks like the chain rule is applied as expected:

```
(%i15) diff('φ(x/a), x);
                                  x
                              x φ(-)
                                  a
(%o15)                      - ------
                                 2
                                a
(%i16) ev(%, nouns);
                                    2
                                   x
                                - ----
                                     2
                                  2 a
                            x %e
(%o16)               - --------------------
                                          2
                       sqrt(2) sqrt(%pi) a
```

Comment: @ Robert Dodier unfortunately both your suggestions do **not** work. Any other ideas?